# How to get textbox to show fraction format

Tags: textbox, format, userform, fractions

How to get Me.TextBox15 to show 3/4" not 0.75? Can we change the format of a textbox?

```
If Me.ComboBox15.Text = "CARBON" And Me.ComboBox16.Text = "150" Then
            Me.TextBox15.Value = Sheets("SHEET2").Range("F56")
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close.

```
Me.TextBox1.Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(Me.TextBox1.Value, "?/?") & Chr(34)
```

However, this will likely show you whole numbers like "4" as "4/1". It is the same, but not really as aesthetically pleasing. Another thing to consider is that fractions like .33333 repeating will not show up as 1/3, rather they will show as 33333/100000. I doubt there is an easy method to get a repeating decimal into a "nice" fraction. The `Chr(34)` at the end will add the single quote to the end of the string.

Good Luck!